# How to set default TIME in angular primeng p-calendar v5.2.7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I have used p-calendar for date and time selection in project and set [minDate]="dateTime" so it is considering current date and time if I click on Today button but I need default time to 00:00 if I click on Today.

Here's my code of p-calendar

```
<p-calendar class="date" (onSelect)="onChangeDate()" [(ngModel)]="model.start_date"
  [minDate]="dateTime" [showIcon]="true" [showTime]="true" showButtonBar="true"
 [formControl]="form.controls['start_date']" [readonlyInput]="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove [showTime]="true" to view 00:00:00 because I don't know if an event to customize button Today exists.

Comment: Yes! the event for today button click exist in primeNg v5.2.7 which is used to perform necessary task when click on p-calendar Today button.